# How to create data serie in Postgresql without function generate_series

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create data series with the value from 0 to 100 with a step of 0.1
Unfortunately, function generate_series() does not work with my database.
does anyone know any other way to create a series like this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I wonder the version of your DB...

Comment: Every Postgres version supports `generate_series()` - are you sure you are using Postgres? What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: You are not using Postgres if you don't have  `generate_series()`.  Please correctly identify the database you are using.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are right. This is not PostgreSQL.  This is Vertica Analitica database

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use recursive cte:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE(c) AS (
  VALUES (0.0)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c + 0.1
  FROM cte
  WHERE c <= 100
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=507222746a1bbb30f508c3b0eea45345)**